Filtration of Vector Bundles under Pullback and Pushforward
Consider a smooth map $f:X\to Y$ and let $E\to X$ and $E'\to Y$ be vector bundles such that $E=f^* E'$, and it admits a filtration
$$0=E_0\subset E_1\subset\cdots\subset E_{n-1}\subset E_n\simeq E.$$
For a generic map $f$, meaning not having any particular property other than smoothness, can we say whether there exists a filtration for the vector bundle $E'$ related to the above filtration by a type of push-forward construction, such as $E'_i:=f_*f^* E_i$ or something similar?

What do you mean by a generic map?

@Sasha Not assuming any property other than smoothness. Maybe, I should add smoothness in the question.

This would contradict to the splitting principle.

@Sasha Can you explain a bit more?

A simple counterexample: let
$$
f \colon \mathrm{Fl}(1,2;3) = X \to \mathrm{Gr}(2,3) = Y
$$
be the natural projection from the flag variety to the Grassmannian and let $E'$ be the tautological bundle of rank 2. Then its pullback has the tautological filtration
$$
L \subset f^*E',
$$
but $E'$ itself does not have any subbundle (i.e., a locally free subsheaf with locally free quotient) of rank 1.
